# How to treat nonlinear radiation term in heat equation using Finite-element method?

Tags: finite-element, nonlinear-equations

I am trying to solve the time-dependant non-linear heat equation with radiation. This equation is coupled to the radiative transfer equation but for the purpose of my question, this does not matter much.
I am using a Crank-Nicolson scheme for the time stepping scheme as well as a Taylor Development of $T^4$.
The Taylor Formula for timestep $n+1$ reads:

$$
T_{n+1}^4 \approx T_{n}^4 + 4T_{n}^3(T_{n+1}-T_{n})
$$

and using the Crank-Nicolson scheme I end up with a term like this in my equation
$$
\frac{T_{n+1}^4+T_{n}^4}{2}
$$
which simplifies with the Taylor's Formula in :

$$
\frac{T_{n+1}^4+T_{n}^4}{2} =-T_{n}^4+2T_{n}^3T_{n+1}
$$

Now I am trying to solve my equation using a finite element method, so over a cell $K$ of my mesh. I can write my temperature as a linear combinaison of trial function $w \in H^2(K)$, such that $T_{n} = \sum_{n_{dof}} T_{n,i}w_i$, with $n_{dof}$ the number of degrees of freedom on my cell $K$. By producting the weak form of my equation, I have to calculate terms like :

for $1 \leq i \leq n_{dof}$ :
$$
\int_K T_{n}^3T_{n+1}w_i dK
$$

Now my problem is how to calculate properly this term. If I replace $T_{n}$ by its linear combinaison of trial function I provided, I end up with

$$
\sum_{n} T_{n+1,n} \int_{K} \left(\sum_{k,l,m} T_{n,k}T_{n,l}T_{n,m}w_kw_lw_mw_nw_i\right) dK
$$

and so if I do that for $1 \leq i \leq n_{dof}$, I end up with a linear algebra expression $MT_{n+1}$, with

$$
M = \left( \int_{K} \left(\sum_{k,l,m} T_{n,k}T_{n,l}T_{n,m}w_kw_lw_mw_nw_i\right) dK\right)_{1 \leq n,i \leq n_{dof}}
$$

Which is quite ugly to work with, but is it the only way to approach this term $T_n^3T_{n+1}$ ?

The only other method I could think of is using an orthonormal basis for $w_i$'s such that $T_{n}^3 = \sum_i^{n_{dof}} T_{n,i}^3w_i$. If I do so the matrix M is like this :

$$
M = \left( \int_{K} \left(\sum_{k} T_{n,k}^3w_kw_nw_i\right) dK\right)_{1 \leq n,i \leq n_{dof}}
$$

Which looks more manageable, but I am not quite sure this is optimal. So my question is : in the finite element method framework, what would be the best way to treat a term like $T_{n}^3T_{n+1}$ ?

Comment: I think that you just need the value of $T^3_n$ in the Gauss points. For that you could use interpolation, of course, but that's a known function for you.

Comment: Look at the linearisation section here
http://mofem.eng.gla.ac.uk/mofem/html/jup_radiation_pluto.html

Comment: @likask while the result on that page is correct, equation 17 and the previous one has a typo. It should read $r(T_k + \delta T ) = r(T_k) + \left. \frac{\partial r}{\partial T}\right|_{T=T_k} \delta T + \ldots$.

Comment: @Bort Thank you for letting me know. Fixed :)

Comment: @nicoguaro Indeed you are right now. I did not realise that I am only concerned by the value at the Gauss point which are known to me, so I just need to put them to the third power and I am good. Thanks

Comment: @likask Thank you for the link. I was aware of the Newton's method for solving such nonlinear problem, but I wanted to try this approach first.